# SQL Server restriction between columns in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
 create table Person(
    FName varchar(15) not null
    ,LName varchar(25) not null
    ,Address varchar(100)
    ,City varchar(30)
    ,State varchar(30)
    ,Zip varchar(10)
    ,Phone varchar(15)
    ,Email varchar(60) unique
    ,UserID varchar(30)
    ,Password varchar(30) not null
    ,CCtype varchar(8)
    ,CCNumber varchar(16)
    ,primary key(UserID)        
);
```

And I want to write a restriction where if there is CCNumber, the CCType can not be empty. The other way around is fine. If I have type I may not have a number, and that is ok.
I have tried those constraints but both are not working as expected when i test.

```
,constraint CCNumber_no_CCType check((CCNumber is null) or (CCType is null))
```

or

```
,constraint CCNumber_no_CCType check((CCNumber is not null) and (CCType is null))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint that you want is:

```
constraint CCNumber_no_CCType check((CCNumber is null) or (CCType is not null))
```

Here is a more general way to think of this.  If you have "if A --> B", then this is true when either B is true or not A is true.

Comment: All answers are correct, thanks guys. I will choose this one because the A->B explanation helped me understand it. I hope rest of you do not get upset :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like so:

```
constraint CCNumber_no_CCType check((CCNumber is null) 
         or (CCNumber is not null and CCType is not null))
```

As others have pointed out, [K map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) simplification should mean that the `or (CCNumber is not null ..` becomes redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a "not" to your first trial's second part:

```
,constraint CCNumber_no_CCType check((CCNumber is null) or (CCType is not null))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constraint CCNumber_no_CCType(CCNumber = '' OR (CCNumber <> '' AND CCType IS NOT NULL))
```